# "Reference package not found. Device Connectivity Component" when delopying C# program to Windows Mobile 6.5 device

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm working on a C# project for windows mobile 6.5 and as of this morning I'm getting "Reference package not found. Device Connectivity Component" whenever I try to deploy.
It builds without errors and was working up until today. I did a bit of looking around and only found dead ends online. As far as I can see there are no clues about that component or package this is a reference to. I think it may be related to Windows CE SQL Compact but that's based on nothing. I've rolled back to an earlier version of my code and cleaned a few times. I'm stumped.

I would greatly appreciate any help even diagnosing this a bit further. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 3.5 SP1

[image: references]
Update: When I disable "Deploy latest version of the .NET Compact Framework (including Service Packs)" it does deploy but then throws errors related to the SQL database which worked previously. assumedly because it doesn't have access to the correct SQL packages.

Update: I also get the same error with the emulator, it builds, the emulator starts but can't deploy, giving the same error.

Update: I think this might have something to do with it. Note the double slashes in the path. I keep removing them. It keeps coming back.

[image]

Update/Correction: I can now deploy to the emulator, I had a problem before but it seems to be ok now. I still can't beploy to the device, same error.

Comment: Can you take screen shots or attach your project file so we see which assemblies are referenced? Further on, as you deployed the project the project successfully previously, does the bin folder on the PC contain a working copy? Or is it a VS connection problem and VS is unable to start the connection? If so, what happens for the deployment a new blank simple project? What happens when you try Tools-ConnectToDevice in VS? ...WindowsMobileDeviceCenter connected?

Comment: Does this help? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2cd23450-3efa-45f7-a5af-06e208e6b144/referenced-package-not-founddevice-connectivity-component?forum=windowsmobiledev

Comment: I assume you have to check your VS installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\CoreCon\1.0\Bin and others for "microsoft.smartdevice.connectivity"

Comment: Thanks josef.

I have attached a screenshot with the references.

As stated above I realized that it will deploy when I disable "Deploy latest version of the .NET Compact Framework (including Service Packs)" but this causes other issues, still it might be reliant information.

The bin folder does contain a working copy and I have an old fork of the project that seems to deploy ok. The connection to the device is ok.

Comment: Re: the link you referenced. As stated above unchecking "deploy... .Net .. framework" does work but causes other issues. Unlike the commenter on that post rechecking "Deploy..." causes the problem to come back.

I am reluctant to delete the references since I inherited this project recently and don't fully understand all the references, I think I'd cause more damage than good.


I just looked at C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\CoreCon\1.0\Bin and found microsoft.smartdevice.connectivity.dll


I wish this error told me specifically which reference was the problem.

Comment: I also went through all the references and manually check that the dll was in the path specified in the properties. I found 2 that had a double slash instead of a single. I'm not sure if this is a problem but I removed them and re added them anyway. The problem still persists.

Comment: I also get the same error with the emulator, I builds, the emulator starts but can't deploy, giving the same error.

Comment: The error is issued as VS is unable to deploy the project. Either VS or the project is corrupted. As you can deploy a simple project it may help to recreate the project using a new project. Just start a new project using a second instance of VS and then copy over all source files from original dir to new project dir (maintening all folders etc) and add all the references needed by the project. Then build and test deploy of the newly created project.

Comment: Thanks, It took a while but I managed to rebuild the whole thing. It seems to have solved the problem but I'm having another issues. I'll close this as soon as I'm sure it's unrelated.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. I wish I had more of an understanding on what went wrong or how to fix it in a more precise way but eventually I just created a new project. Copied the references back in and copy and pasted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who was pulling their hair out like me. I couldn't figure out what was wrong although I still suspect it was something to do with the .NET compact package. Eventually I created a new project, set up the references and copied and pasted the code over. It's not a nice solution but it worked after days of being stuck.

Comment: I feel a little guilty choosing my own answer but it's what did it and there aren't any other answers.

Comment: It seems like allowing Windows Updates will occasionally update the SQL CE packages on your PC. These updates may be compatible with your PC, but they may or may not be compatible with these older Windows Mobile devices (most likely they are incompatible). Reading your original question, I knew what caused the problem. The only real solution would be to turn off the Windows Updates feature - either that, or know specifically which update from Microsoft is addressing the SQL CE package, and then select to block that one.

Comment: I'll look out for that thanks. I am still having trouble with SQL on the device but figured it was a different issue outside the scope of this question. I'm getting a mismatch between the Database file version (3.5) and the SQL server version (3.0).

Comment: I resolved the error with the SQL version by referencing to the 3.5 dll rather than the 3.0 dll. Just to see I tried the same in the project that had the above error but I got the same error on deployment, although you guessing my problem without prompting suggests it might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

HA! I found it! This may not be your solution, but this was how I did it.

See this REF: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Since Microsoft is bad about deleting their old info, I'm going to post it here, too. But basically, if you select a Private Deployment, then Microsoft Updates will not influence your project or update your 3.5 databases to ...whatever the newest stuff from Microsoft is.

### How to: Deploy a SQL Server Compact 3.5 Database with an Application

You have two deployment options for applications that contain SQL Server Compact 3.5 databases. The method of deployment you choose depends on the servicing requirements of your application and whether your users will need administrative credentials on the computer on which the application will be installed.

Following are the deployment options for SQL Server Compact 3.5 databases:

- Traditional Microsoft Windows Installer (Microsoft setup technology)

  - Users need administrative credentials to install the application.
  - SQL Server Compact 3.5 will be serviced by Microsoft Update.
  - Can use ClickOnce deployment.

-or-

- Private file–based deployment (deploying the SQL Server Compact 3.5 DLLs as part of the project)

  - Users do not need administrative credentials to install the application.
  - SQL Server Compact 3.5 will not be serviced by Microsoft Update.
  - Can also use ClickOnce deployment.

### Traditional Windows Installer

Traditional Windows Installer technology is used in both standard Setup and Deployment projects and in ClickOnce deployment. When you deploy a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database, ClickOnce deployment provides an option that automatically installs SQL Server Compact 3.5 if it is not detected on the target computer. For this reason, ClickOnce is the preferred method of deployment for applications that include SQL Server Compact 3.5 databases (as opposed to creating a custom action in a Setup and Deployment project).

ClickOnce deployment has been updated so that it automatically includes the SQL Server Compact 3.5 runtime as a prerequisite for applications that include SQL Server Compact 3.5 databases. It also recognizes .sdf files as data files and sets these to the correct publish status.

Creating a ClickOnce deployment for an application that contains a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database consists of configuring the proper publish information in the **Project Designer**.

**To use Windows Installer technology for ClickOnce deployment of an application that contains a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database**

1. To open the Project Designer, in Solution Explorer/Database Explorer, double-click My Project if you are working on a Visual Basic project (or Properties if you are working on a C# project).
2. Click the **Publish** tab.
3. Click **Application Files** and set the .sdf file to **Data File (Auto)**. *(This setting notifies the installer to treat this as a local data file and to put it in the Data Directory.)*
4. Click **Prerequisites** and select **SQL Server Compact 3.5**. *(This setting notifies the installer to check whether the SQL Server Compact 3.5 runtime exists and to install it from the Internet if it is not found.)*

**Creating the Installer** After the publish information is configured, create the installer.

To create the installer

1. In the **Publishing Location** box, type the Web site, FTP server, or file path to publish the installer to.
2. Click **Publish Now** to create the installer.

The application is ready to be installed. Go to the location you published to, and install the application to verify.

### Private File-Based Deployment

*Private file–based deployment* refers to the process of including the required SQL Server Compact 3.5 DLLs as files in the project (as opposed to a reference to DLLs already on the target computer). If you include the necessary DLLs with the application, the requirement to install SQL Server Compact 3.5 is removed. Therefore, the administrative credentials are no longer needed.

You can use ClickOnce deployment technology for private file–based deployment. If you do, you must remember to clear the SQL Server Compact 3.5 prerequisite so that the Setup program does not install it.

**To deploy a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database by using private file–based deployment**

1. To open the **Project Designer**, in **Solution Explorer/Database Explorer**, double-click **My Project** if you are working on a Visual Basic project (or **Properties** if you are working on a C# project).
2. Click the **Publish** tab.
3. Click **Prerequisites** and then clear the check box for **SQL Server Compact 3.5**.
4. Close the **Project Designer**.
5. Go to the directory that contains the SQL Server Compact 3.5 DLLs. These are located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5`.
6. Select the seven SQL Server Compact 3.5 DLLs and copy them:

   - sqlceca35.dll
   - sqlcecompact35.dll
   - sqlceer35EN.dll
   - sqlceme35.dll
   - sqlceoledb35.dll
   - sqlceqp35.dll
   - sqlcese35.dll
7. Paste the DLLs into the project in **Solution Explorer/Database Explorer**.
8. Select all seven DLLs in **Solution Explorer/Database Explorer** and open the **Properties** window.
9. Set the **Copy to Output Directory** property to **Copy if newer**. *(This will replace any earlier DLLs in an existing application with the newer ones if the application is updated.)*
10. Click the **Show All Files** button in **Solution Explorer/Database Explorer**.
11. Expand the **References** node.
12. Select **System.Data.SqlServerCe**.
13. Set the **Copy Local** property to **True**. *(Because your development computer has the SqlServerCe DLLs in the global assembly cache, you must configure the application to use the DLLs in the output directory.)*
14. Right-click the project in **Solution Explorer/Database Explorer** and select **Publish** to open the Publish Wizard.
15. Complete the wizard to publish the application.

The application is ready to be installed. Go to the location you published to, and install the application to verify.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I got it to work by closing visual studio, renaming the directory:

> C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\CoreCon

Then reopening visual studio and the deploy worked.